# Parent Class member function using instances of child class c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a coursework that involves implementing two classes, one to store Matrix objects and a child of this for SquareMatrix objects. We have to implement member functions to be able to solve an equation of the form Ax = b, with A being the matrix, x being the vector we want to find and b being a known vector.

I've implemented this in the case of a SquareMatrix since it is not too hard to do with Gaussian elimination. The method that the coursework says we should use to solve the case with a non-square matrix is to solve A'Ax = A'b with ' meaning transpose. A'A is now a square matrix so this can be solved using Gaussian elimination also.

What I wanted to know was whether it is a valid thing to do to create a SquareMatrix object in the Matrix solve function and then use the SquareMatrix member solve to solve the system. So for instance if in SquareMatrix I have

```
Matrix SquareMatrix::solve(Matrix& b){
    //stuff that solves (*this) * x = b for x and returns x
}
```

Could I then in Matrix.cpp have

```
Matrix Matrix::solve(Matrix& b){
    //make the matrix into a square
    SquareMatrix AtransposeA = (this->transpose())*(*this);

    //update rhs of equation accordingly 
    Matrix Atransposeb = (this->transpose()) * b;

    //Call SquareMatrix solve to solve the problem.
    Matrix x = AtransposeA.solve(Atransposeb);
    return x;
}
```

So I'm making the matrix square by multiplying by its transpose and then calling the SquareMatrix solve function. I'm relatively new to C++ and haven't 100% gotten my head around inheritance so I'm not sure if this a valid, or sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this a valid, or sensible thing to do.

It is valid to use a derived class, to implement a function of parent class in some cases.

Whether it makes sense for `SquareMatrix` to be derived from `Matrix` is another consideration. To know the answer to that question, you'll need to consider your design, and outline all class invariants and member function pre- and post-conditions of `Matrix` and then consider whether `SquareMatrix` can satisfy them all.

Comment: Thanks, since the coursework explicitly asks us to derive SquareMatrix from Matrix we have no choice, though I see your point. Thanks for clearing up whether using a derived class in the parent class is valid though